# How to check unwrapError

Tags: mithril.js

```
var users = m.request({
  method: "GET",
  url: "hoge.json",
  unwrapSuccess: function(response) {

    return response;
  },
  unwrapError: function(response) {
    //return response.error;
    return "404 error";
  }
});

users.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); 
});
```

After delete "hoge.json".

I want to catch "404 error",but

> uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

---

2016/2/18 add

I want to test alert ("unwrapError");

Below code is always alert ("unwrapSuccess");

How to change below code?

What is the unwrapError?

▼js

```
var users = m.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "hoge.json",
    unwrapSuccess: function(response) {
          alert ("unwrapSuccess");
          return response;
    },
    unwrapError: function(response) {
          alert ("unwrapError");
          return "error";
    }
});


users.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); 
});
```

▼hoge.json

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]
```

Comment: Have you checked that the JSON file is properly formatted and has no errors? You can use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Is json need to be correct?　404 error  is Off the subject?　Any case become unwrapError?

Comment: Yes, JSON needs to be properly formatted, what I'm saying is that the uncaught syntax error message might mean that the error is on the JSON side, maybe if you add the hoge.json file it will be easier to tell

Comment: I add the hoge.json file.

Comment: I see nothing wrong there, I put in place a jsfiddle and it works https://jsfiddle.net/patillades/macym2c4/ Is there any more code involved that can be causing the error?

Comment: It is the opposite. How do I alert ("unwrapError") from this state? On purpose I want to have to deliberately unwrapError state.What is the unwrapError? 400error? 404error? something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [mithril's source code](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/mithril.js#L2001) you will see that `m.request` is just a wrapper for the `XMLHttpRequest` API. And that's what happens when the request's `readyState` attribute changes:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            options.onload({type: "load", target: xhr})
        } else {
            options.onerror({type: "error", target: xhr})
        }
    }
}
```

So mithril's `unwrapError` callback will be called whenever the response status is not a 2xx.

I [updated the fiddle calling a URL that returns a 500 response](https://jsfiddle.net/patillades/macym2c4/2/) and now the `unwrapError` is called.

Comment: Thank you! This is what is the answer that I wanted to know me!